# How to recreate this logic using a sql case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT

    'IsActive' = 

FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Permissions p ON u.Id = p.UserId
```

I need to add some logic to the above query to get the same result as if I was doing the below (which is pseudo code).

Is this possible with a case statement?

```
if( 
    (p.Approved && 
        (p.secondaryApproval == null ||  (p.SecondaryApproval != null && p.secondaryApproval)
    )
  )
```

The logic in the `if` statement above determines with `IsActive` should be true.

Can I somehow use a sql case statement to `mimick` this logic in my query?

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return one or another value - but it's **NOT** a flow control statement like in other programming languages

Comment: `p.SecondaryApproval != null` is not necessary after the `||`, because it's a short-circuiting operator.

Comment: Although it looks *a lot* like C#, the original author said it was psuedocode, so "short-circuiting operators" don't necessarily apply. Obviously not a big deal, of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN p.Approved=1 AND (p.SecondaryApproval IS NULL OR p.SecondaryApproval=1) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS IsActive
FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Permissions p ON u.Id = p.UserId
```

Note that it is not necessary to test `p.SecondaryApproval` for non-nullness on the other side of the `OR`, both in your SQL and in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT *  FROM Users u
    INNER JOIN Permissions p ON u.Id = p.UserId
Where p.Approved = true
and (
    p.secondaryApproval is null
    OR
    (p.SecondaryApproval is not null and p.secondaryApproval = true)
    )
```